# Why PayTm refund API is returning "System Error" with 501 status code in dot net core application?

Tags: c#, paytm

My application is on dot net core 2.1. I am using PayTm dll. Everything is working except Refund API. Always it is returning 501 with the PENDING status & message as "System Error".

Please check my below code.

```
string jsonData = "{ 'mid':'546yrtrgfhrtrgfgfg','orderId':'ROLI0Z5URRTJQ','txnType':'REFUND','refundAmount':'10','txnId':'2019063011121281120949176094516','refId':'REF978000015'}";
            string paytmChecksum = paytm.CheckSum.generateCheckSumByJson("09A76423dfertg", jsonData);
            HttpWebRequest connection = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://securegw.paytm.in/refund/apply");
            connection.Method = "POST";
            connection.Headers.Add("signature", paytmChecksum);
            using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(connection.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                requestWriter.Write(jsonData);
            }
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(connection.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseData = string.Empty;
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                return responseData;
            }
```

Please Note that: I have tried different checksum generation methods (like generateChecksumForRefund, generateChecksum and generateChecksumByJson), every time I am getting the same error. I am using production keys.

Comment: HTTP 501 error is the [not implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/501) error. If that is the case there is nothing you can do about it in your code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But payTm have given the official documentation for refund API. Without implementing,I believe they will not provide the documentation. Please visit the url for their documentation.  https://developer.paytm.com/docs/refund-api/

Comment: The exact Response is :  {"head":{"responseTimestamp":"1562473442033","version":"v1"},
"body":{"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"PENDING","resultCode":"501","resultMsg":"System Error."}}}

Comment: @Roushan, any luck on this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error doc error 501 is an system error inside payTm.

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/refund-status-api/

There is nothing wrong from your side, I suggest you to wait a few hours and try again. it will automatically work